# Multiple HTTP Requests with RxJS, with parameters

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3

I call this api

`https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ads/`

I grab the `id` of each ad and then I append it to this url

`https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=24385`

My code is

```
  loadAds() {
    let i = 0;
    this.HttpClient.get(ENV.site_url + ENV.ads_url)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.ads = this.ads.concat(res);

        this.HttpClient.get(ENV.site_url + ENV.ads_thumb_url + this.ads[i].id + "&&ads/" + this.ads[i].id)
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.items = this.items.concat(res);
            console.log(ENV.site_url + ENV.ads_thumb_url + this.ads[i].id + "&&ads/" + this.ads[i].id);
            i++;
          })
      }
      )
  }
```

The code works but:

- I end up with two different arrays, I'm not able to merge them correctly into an array `items`
- I hate the fact that I have to do two separate subscriptions, it works but it feels wrong

Basically I want to end up with an array containing all the items from both endpoints.

So object `id=24385` should return an array of

`https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ads/24385`

And

`https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=24385`

Comment: from what I see here... you get an array of ids and you want to call another url with each id?

Comment: @SurajRao yes and then merge the results from the first request with the results of the second request so i can iterate over 1 array in the view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is merge the two lists using `concatMap`. 
For example:

```
getService1(id1).pipe(
   // take array1 and return [array1, array2]
   concatMap( array1=> return zip(of(array1), getService2(array1[information])))
   // concat Array1 and array2 
   map( [array1, array2] =>  array1.concat(array2))
)
.subscribe( combinedArray => ...)
```

If your services emit 1 item each, you can replace `concatMap` with `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, or `exhaustMap`; they all behave same in this context. Additionally, you can also substitute `zip` with `forkJoin`. On the contrary, if your services emit more than 1 value, you will have to choose the one that behaves according to your needs.

Comment: was thinking of switchMap and forkJoin... any reason zip is better?

Comment: Forkjoin won't work, you need the result of the first service before callibg the second. switchMap, concatMap,  exhaustMap, mergeMap work and are equivalent if your services emit one value.

Comment: the _second call_ from switchMap would be forkJoin

Comment: Yes forkJoin (of (array1), service2) looks ok

Answer (score 2):

You can switchMap to second call where you do `forkJoin` (send all calls and wait for the final array of response)

```
this.HttpClient.get(ENV.site_url + ENV.ads_url).pipe(
  switchMap(res => {
    this.ads = this.ads.concat(res);
    let obs  = this.ads.map(ad => this.HttpClient.get(ENV.site_url + ENV.ads_thumb_url + ad.id + "&&ads/" + ad.id);//create an observable array
      return forkJoin(...obs).pipe(map(res=>res.concat(this.ads)));//map the response with initial array and return concatenated array.
  })
  ).subscribe(finalArray =>{
})
```

Comment: the problem is that `this.HttpClient.get(ENV.site_url + ENV.ads_thumb_url + ad.id + "&&ads/" + ad.id));` will return only the images and you can check that here `https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=24408&&ads/24408` That's what I tried to do but can't combine both in the url. As you can see, the array you get shows only the thumbnails with no information regarding the ad title, city, phone etc

Comment: I was trying to do a similar thing yesterday and got stuck https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308750/is-it-possible-to-combine-two-rest-endpoints-in-the-url

Comment: it looks like you may have to check the api from which you will get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who answered, I'm gonna pick a randomly accepted answer because they're excellent, I solved it like this though.

Provider:

```
  getAds(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(ENV.site_url + ENV.ads_url)
      .flatMap((ads: any[]) => {
        if (ads.length > 0) {
          return Observable.forkJoin(
            ads.map((ad: any) => {
              return this.http.get(ENV.site_url + ENV.ads_thumb_url + ad.id)
                .map((res: any) => {
                  let media: any = res;
                  ad.media = media;
                  return ad;
                });
            })
          );
        }
        return Observable.of([]);
      });
  }
```

and the provider is

Home.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.adsProvider.getAds().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.items = data;
    });
  }
```

Credit to [this article: Combining Observables in series and in parallel](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/)